# JavaScript return by reference

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a `variable` and a `function` which edit the variable value.

But it's not working and I don't know why.

And what is the correct way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
function t(){
  var test = 1;

  var changeTest = function(){
    test++;
  }

  return {
    changeTest:changeTest,
    test:test
  }
}

var b = t();
b.changeTest();
console.log(b.test) // the value is 1 not 2
```

Comment: it does not change the value in the object, only the variable `test` of the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `test` is a primitive and so it is indeed not a reference.

A solution: make the exposed `test` property a getter, so that the value of the private `test` variable is retrieved at the moment the property is accessed:

```
return {
  changeTest:changeTest,
  get test() { return test }
}
```

```js
function t(){
  var test = 1;

  var changeTest = function(){
    test++;
  }

  return {
    changeTest,
    get test() { return test }
  }
}

var b = t();
b.changeTest();
console.log(b.test);
```

With this pattern, the `test` variable remains private, and you only expose the features you want to. So in this case you allow explicitly to *read* the `test` value, but not to *write* it.

NB: you can shorten the object literal notation to just:

```
  return {
    changeTest,
    get test() { return test }
  }
```

Comment: Best and cleanest solution thanks, I Like the readonly feature

Answer (score 2):

In `changeTest` you have to use `this.test` instead of `test`.

```js
function t(){
  var test = 1;

  var changeTest = function(){
    this.test++;
  }

  return {
    changeTest:changeTest,
    test:test
  }
}

var b = t();
b.changeTest();
console.log(b.test) // the value is 1 not 2
```

Comment: It's not working in some case, for example if I want to change in nested function I should bind this, and a lot of code, but it's working thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to increase inside of the function, you need to use `this` keyword inside, just like the following:

```js
function t(){
  const changeTest = function() { this.test++; };
  return { changeTest, test: 1 };
}

const b = t();
console.log('original value', b.test);
b.changeTest();
console.log('increased value', b.test);
```

The reason is why it is happening because you are not modifying the value inside, it is called lexical closure what you face with, as the documentations states:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Using the `this` keyword the code accesses the proper `test` variable.

For further explanation please read further here:

1. Closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
2. this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

I hope this helps!

Comment: But then why have a `test` variable at all?

Comment: Thank you, It's working, I'm using @trincot solution, All answer are working, I accept this answer because of number of vote

Comment: Please note that the `test` variable is not used in this solution (except for assigning the initial value), and so you don't actually have a private member, which I suppose was the original intention. If you would inspect the value of the local variable `test`, you would notice it actually does not increase.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the suggestion, just corrected!

Comment: I see reverted the change, so my previous comment is still applicable.

Comment: @trincot I think I see now, thanks! Just updated my answer.

Comment: OK, so now you have just changed your approach and taken the solution I provided in my answer two hours ago :/ I don't think that is quite fair.

Comment: You can still use your original approach though. Just try to do it without `let test` and return `{ changeTest, test: 1 }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203424/discussion-between-norbitrial-and-trincot).

Comment: @trincot you are right, its not fair. I changed the best answer